# why is my active rigid body object not stopping after falling?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a model of a coin that I want to fall on the ground. The issue is that once it hits the ground its not stopping and sometimes falls below the ground.
all rotation and scale transform has been done to both objects

[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kL2MMuhX6sIPWmI0wT3tQWxKEsawz3ho/view?usp=sharing)

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CIvrN5e39gkFka1WsRdnWoyrfqIw0HEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could scale the floor and coin x 3 then apply the scale, and also give a *Shape > Box* to the floor and *Shape > Convex Hull* to the coin. It seems to make the calculation easier:

[image]